# Is it best to have multiple user models or 1 user model with multiple profiles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I currently have one user model and one user profile for that model.  In total, i will need either 4 user models and 4 user profiles or 1 user model and 4 profiles.  Not ever profile will contain the same info/data, so which do you think is the best way to pursue what I am trying to do?  I am currently utilizing devise for authentication.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever get an answer about this?